# uib-typeahead not working but typeahead is in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-bootstrap

trying to get ui the Bootstrap uib-typeahead to work on a search bar async.  I'm getting the correct data response, an array of objects:

```
[ { username: 'yaboi' },
  { username: 'Gepeto' },
  { username: 'Zanbato' },
  { username: 'Colonel' },
  { username: 'Hipster' },
  { username: 'jacob' } ]
```

but it doesn't seem to filter or work with uib-typeahead.  Using just typeahead though I can get a response, but its not filtering out correctly and I'm pretty sure its depreciated because its throwing a warning in the console that success isn't a function.

Is there something wrong with my loop?

```
<input id="giftUser" ng-model="asyncSelected" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Users" uib-typeahead="username for username in getUsers($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingUsers" typeahead-no-results="noResults">
                <i ng-show="loadingUsers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
                <div ng-show="noResults">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - I was using an older version of ui-bootstrap.  Everything after 0.14 needs uib, everything before that doesn't.